# Application Gateway with Web App Backend (domain not resolving)

Tags: azure-application-gateway, azure-dns

I have a both a multi and single site Application Gateway with a Web App backend pool. Settings at the backend pool point to port 80 (http).

I am using a personal domain of example: [www.mydomain.club](http://www.mydomain.club) and using either web host or DNS. When I enter [www.mydomain.club](http://www.mydomain.club) into the browser, it resolves to https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net:80 in the browser bar, with error message on page indicating that I cannot reach the site.

It seems like the DNS/host recognizes the domain resolving required, but tries push for port 443 (https), but indicates there is a port 80, while returning the web app address (even though I'm going through the application gate). If I restrict access the web app, I get a 401 error.

I have tried:

1. CNAME pointing to the DNS name for Application Gateway IP - mydns.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
2. A recording using both @ and WWW pointing to the Gateway IP.
3. Overriding the host name in the backend settings.

Comment: Hi @kay1188, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   As seen from the URL, i.e., **‘https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net:80’**, the **Azure webapp website points to ‘HTTPS’ port 443 but you might have configured the webapp’s website incorrectly in the backend pool for ‘HTTP’ port 80**. Due to which when you are **trying to access the ‘www.mydomain.club’ domain name over the internet, it is redirecting you to the ‘https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net:80’ URL as you have configured it so in the application gateway’s backend pool**.

Thus, would suggest you to *`please reconfigure the ‘https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net:80’ to only ‘https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net’ in the application gateway’s backend pool`*. This will ensure that the website ‘www.mydomain.club’ is redirected correctly to the above said website only and the pages hosted in that webapp will be displayed correctly.

•   Secondly, please do ensure that you have **created an ‘A’ host record for ‘www’ in the public DNS zone for ‘mydomain.club’ domain** which will ensure that the **website is hosted on a publicly available IP address and domain name**. Also, since you want the **website domain name, i.e., ‘www.mydomain.club’ to be redirected to the application gateway URI/FQDN, i.e., ‘xyz.eastus.cloudapp.net’, then create a CNAME record for ‘www.mydomain.club’ address with the alias as ‘xyz.eastus.cloudapp.net’**. This will `ensure that when trying to access the domain name ‘www.mydomain.club’, it will be redirected to the application gateway’s URL and will be displaying the backend site web page` accordingly as defined in the routing rules and the listener rules.

This will ensure that, you will not encounter 401 error when accessing the website DNS, i.e., ‘www.mydomain.club’ and it opens correctly.

Please find the below documentation link for more details: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/379193/application-gateway-with-a-custom-domain-name.html**